# SASS Function not working as expected

Tags: css, sass

I have a SCSS mixin and function for preloading background images:

```
$preloaded-images:null;
@function preload-image($image-url) {
  $preloaded-images: $preloaded-images url(#{$image-url});
  @return $preloaded-images;
}

@mixin background-image-generator($img-name) {
  background: url(../images/backgrounds/#{$img-name}/#{$img-name}.jpg) no-repeat center center local;
  $tmp: preload-image('../images/backgrounds/#{$img-name}/#{$img-name}.jpg');
}

body:before {
  display:none;
  content:$preloaded-images;
}

.background1 {
  @include background-image-generator('plaits');
}
```

I expect it to return the following css:

```
body:before {
  display: none; 
  content: url(../images/backgrounds/plaits/plaits.jpg);
}

.background1 {
  background: url(../images/backgrounds/plaits/plaits.jpg) no-repeat center center local; }
```

It nearly does but the content for body:before is null. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ahhh I see what you are trying to do now and why the `$tmp` is set.

The issue is that SASS will go from top to bottom so when it gets to `body:before` it checks `$preloaded-images` and notices its `null` so it doesn't assign anything.

`$preloaded-images` is only assigned a value when `@mixin background-image-generator` is called so that has to be called first. So actually switching them works (I tested it).

```
$preloaded-images:null;
@function preload-image($image-url) {
  $preloaded-images: $preloaded-images url(#{$image-url});
  @return $preloaded-images;
}

@mixin background-image-generator($img-name) {
  background: url(../images/backgrounds/#{$img-name}/#{$img-name}.jpg) no-repeat center center local;
  $tmp: preload-image('../images/backgrounds/#{$img-name}/#{$img-name}.jpg');
}

.background1 {
  @include background-image-generator('plaits');
}

// move this below so background-image-generator will run
body:before {
  display:none;
  content:$preloaded-images;
}
```

And this spits out for me (my minifier at work).

```
.background1{background:url(../images/backgrounds/plaits/plaits.jpg) no-repeat center center local}body:before{display:none;content: url(../images/backgrounds/plaits/plaits.jpg)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you be able to provide an example? Can I achieve what I am trying to do? I thought I was defining it outside the mixing already

Comment: @LukeCaldwell I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. Your `preload-image` function isn't really being used anywhere. In your `background-image-generator` function, you store the value in a `$tmp` but like I mentioned in my answer that variable isn't accessible anywhere so its just kind of sitting there.

Comment: I want to add the images that I pass to the background-image-generator mixin to be content in body:after tag. Every time I use the mixin I want the image added to the list. I was following http://yoranbrondsema.com/elegantly-preload-background-images-sass/

Comment: Thank you but this is still not working for me. I copied and pasted your code into http://sassmeister.com and the body:after content is still empty

Comment: @LukeCaldwell hmm interesting it depends on what version Sass is on. Trying going to the control panel and setting the version to be 3.3.14. It seems to work on that version. Unfortunately, I can't attest to this site and how reliable it is -- I am using grunt with libsass to build my Sass out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85050/discussion-between-aug-and-luke-caldwell).